# Receiving build errors when attempting to debug project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am receiving this error when try to build and debug the code:

*******"Could not load file or assembly 'DTI.FaxManJr, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)'  sqlrd7  C:\Visual Studio Projects\pbrs\LC"*******

I am workin with in a 64-bit Windows 10 OS and my project is using the framework ***.NET 4.6.1***

I have tried removing and adding in this dll and any dependencies, unblocking them after I download them, so they aren't blocked by the firewall. I have also moved the dll in the root folder, bin folder, and it still is not working. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

p.s. we do have a license for this dll, that file is in the root folder of the project. Here are some xml tags I noticed in my project.

```
<Reference Include="DTI.FaxMan.Core, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3ff15c974c5defd8, processorArchitecture=x86">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <Reference Include="DTI.FaxMan.Core">
      <HintPath>Lib\DTI.FaxMan.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DTI.FaxMan.Print, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3ff15c974c5defd8, processorArchitecture=x86">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <Reference Include="DTI.FaxMan.Print">
      <HintPath>Lib\DTI.FaxMan.Print.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DTI.FaxManJr, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
```

Comment: Architecture incompatibility? x64 vs x86 Check your library bitness against your current target architecture

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to check for that, if I'm being honest. Could you elaborate more? please :)

Comment: I think I may have identified the problem you're referring to, Steve. Here's what I noticed in my vbproj file: